# CALCULATE PERCENT BY DEVIDING AGREGATED VALUE ON TOTAL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query that aggregates a column by a category and then find a percent of that category from total categories

```
WITH USERS_ENERGY AS 
(SELECT D.REGION_ID,E.YEAR_DESC,HOME_TYPE_ID,OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID,B.ELECTRICITY_TYPE_KEY,SUM(WEIGHT_FINAL) HH_BY_ELECTRICITY_TYPE
FROM 
R_FACT_HOUSING_UNIT B
JOIN 
RR_DIM_SAMPLE C ON B.SAMPLE_FORM_ID=C.SAMPLE_FORM_ID
JOIN 
R_DIM_PLACES D ON C.FRAM_PLACE_ID=D.PLACE_ID
JOIN 
R_DIM_YEAR E ON B.ROUND_YEAR=E.ID
JOIN
R_DIM_HOME_TYPE F ON F.HOME_TYPE_ID=B.HOME_TYPE_KEY
JOIN
R_DIM_OWNERSHIP_TYPE G ON G.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID=B.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_KEY
WHERE B.ELECTRICITY_TYPE_KEY IN(8200002,8200001)
GROUP BY D.REGION_ID,E.YEAR_DESC,HOME_TYPE_ID,OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID,B.ELECTRICITY_TYPE_KEY),
ALL_HH AS 
(
SELECT REGION_ID,YEAR_DESC,HOME_TYPE_ID,OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID,SUM(B.WEIGHT_FINAL) TOTAL_HH
FROM  
R_FACT_HOUSING_UNIT B  
JOIN 
RR_DIM_SAMPLE C ON B.SAMPLE_FORM_ID=C.SAMPLE_FORM_ID
JOIN 
R_DIM_PLACES D ON C.FRAM_PLACE_ID=D.PLACE_ID
JOIN 
R_DIM_YEAR E ON B.ROUND_YEAR=E.ID
JOIN
R_DIM_HOME_TYPE F ON F.HOME_TYPE_ID=B.HOME_TYPE_KEY
JOIN
R_DIM_OWNERSHIP_TYPE G ON G.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID=B.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_KEY
WHERE B.ELECTRICITY_TYPE_KEY IN(8200002,8200001)
GROUP BY REGION_ID,YEAR_DESC,HOME_TYPE_ID,OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID
)
SELECT A."REGION_ID",A."YEAR_DESC",A."HOME_TYPE_ID",A."OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID",A."ELECTRICITY_TYPE_KEY",A."HH_BY_ELECTRICITY_TYPE",TOTAL_HH FROM USERS_ENERGY A,ALL_HH B WHERE A.REGION_ID=B.REGION_ID AND A.YEAR_DESC=B.YEAR_DESC AND A.HOME_TYPE_ID=B.HOME_TYPE_ID AND A.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID=B.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID
```

that was the view I created.
when I tried to test it gave me wrong results

this was my test

```
SELECT ELECTRICITY_TYPE_KEY,SUM(HH_BY_ELECTRICITY_TYPE),SUM(TOTAL_HH)FROM MASDAR_HEN_3_A_A T 
GROUP BY ELECTRICITY_TYPE_KEY
ORDER BY  ELECTRICITY_TYPE_KEY
```

the result was:

[image]
but it supposes to be:

[image]

so if you devide values on total and add them it supposes to give 100%

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost impossible to follow.  Some helpful advice for your query-writing:

- Always use MEANINGFUL table alases, such as `y` for `dim_year`.  Arbitrary letters are hard to follow.
- **Always use proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax.**  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

As for your view, I think you just need analytic functions.  A simpler version (assuming I haven't make mistakes on the table aliases):

```
SELECT p.REGION_ID, y.YEAR_DESC, ht.HOME_TYPE_ID, ot.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID, hu.ELECTRICITY_TYPE_KEY,
        SUM(WEIGHT_FINAL) as HH_BY_ELECTRICITY_TYPE
       SUM(SUM(WEIGHT_FINAL)) OVER (REGION_ID,YEAR_DESC, HOME_TYPE_ID, OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID) as TOTAL_HH
FROM R_FACT_HOUSING_UNIT hu JOIN 
     RR_DIM_SAMPLE 
     ON hu.SAMPLE_FORM_ID = s.SAMPLE_FORM_ID JOIN 
     R_DIM_PLACES p
     ON s.FRAM_PLACE_ID=  p.PLACE_ID JOIN 
     R_DIM_YEAR y
     ON hu.ROUND_YEAR = y.ID JOIN
     R_DIM_HOME_TYPE ht
     ON ht.HOME_TYPE_ID = hu.HOME_TYPE_KEY JOIN
     R_DIM_OWNERSHIP_TYPE ot
     ON ot.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID=  hu.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_KEY
WHERE hu.ELECTRICITY_TYPE_KEY IN (8200002, 8200001)
GROUP BY p.REGION_ID, y.YEAR_DESC, ht.HOME_TYPE_ID, ot.OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID, hu.ELECTRICITY_TYPE_KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a `RATIO_TO_REPORT` analytic function to compute % of total for you.

```
SELECT
    d.region_id,
    e.year_desc,
    home_type_id,
    ownership_type_id,
    b.electricity_type_key,
    SUM(weight_final) hh_by_electricity_type,
    100*RATIO_TO_REPORT(SUM(weight_final) OVER ( PARTITION BY REGION_ID,YEAR_DESC, HOME_TYPE_ID, OWNERSHIP_TYPE_ID ) pct_of_total
FROM
    r_fact_housing_unit    b
    JOIN rr_dim_sample          c ON b.sample_form_id = c.sample_form_id
    JOIN r_dim_places           d ON c.fram_place_id = d.place_id
    JOIN r_dim_year             e ON b.round_year = e.id
    JOIN r_dim_home_type        f ON f.home_type_id = b.home_type_key
    JOIN r_dim_ownership_type   g ON g.ownership_type_id = b.ownership_type_key
WHERE
    b.electricity_type_key IN (
        8200002,
        8200001
    )
GROUP BY
    d.region_id,
    e.year_desc,
    home_type_id,
    ownership_type_id,
    b.electricity_type_key;
```

Here is another example, using the Oracle data dictionary for input data, for readers who do not have data model to test with:

```
SELECT owner, 
       sum(bytes) total_bytes, 
       100*ratio_to_report(sum(bytes)) over () pct_of_total
FROM   dba_segments
GROUP BY owner;
```